# Start and end time on click event

Tags: angular, typescript, timer

I want to implement a start and end time on click event .
Time should be in the format
00.00 until counter hits 1 hour. After 1 hour the counter should be
00.00.00 format.

```
SetInterval(()=>{
Let timer = new Date().getTime()/1000;

},1000)
```

I dont know how to get the time which starts at 00.00 and ends when the user clicks the event

Comment: I don't really get what you mean. If you want a start and end time, why do you need a interval at all?

Comment: I mean when I click start , the timer should begin as the above mentioned format and should pause once I click end button

Comment: why not just `this.start = new Date()` and then `this.end = new Date()`? Then you can calculate the time with `this.start.getTime() - this.end.getTime()`.

Comment: When I click the start , the time should begin and should reflect on html . As soon as I stop it should show the time elapsed since the start time . @marcel